# Docker and Mysql: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, docker

When running mysqld in this Dockerfile (on my Linux box,  Linux 12.04)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:precise
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server

CMD ["/usr/sbin/mysqld"]
```

I get `mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied`

Whereas running it on my Mac through boot2docker `mysqld` starts up just fine.

I have tried different base docker images:

- phusion/baseimage:0.9.8
- phusion/baseimage:0.9.1
- ubuntu:latest

I have run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` (including updating Mysql) on the host system, I have rebooted the host system.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Info about my system:

```
$ docker version
Client version: 0.9.0
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 2b3fdf2
Server version: 0.9.0
Git commit (server): 2b3fdf2
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Last stable version: 0.9.0

$ docker info
Containers: 37
Images: 340
Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Dirs: 414
WARNING: No swap limit support

$ uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal 3.8.0-37-generic #53~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 21:37:54 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer to leeduhem comments about permissions of libz.so.1:

```
$ ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 10  2011 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3.4

$ ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 92720 Nov 10  2011 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
```

Changing permissions with

```
$ chmod +x  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
```

I still get the error.

Running `strace -o /tmp/mysql.strace mysqld` and `cat /tmp/mysql.strace` gives

```
execve("/usr/sbin/mysqld", ["mysqld"], [/* 7 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x7f4d41f7c000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4d403c5000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/lib/tls/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls", 0x7fff713907f0)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib", 0x7fff713907f0)            = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7fff713907f0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff713907f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", 0x7fff713907f0)        = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
writev(2, [{"mysqld", 6}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libz.so.1", 9}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"Permission denied", 17}, {"\n", 1}], 10) = 107
```

---

Looking at the directories /lib and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu that the trace seems to indicate are not permitted:

```
$ ls -ld /lib
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Dec 16 13:42 /lib

$ ls -ld /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 17 13:39 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: What is the permissions of `libz.so.1`? Please include the output of `ls -l /path/to/libz.so.1` in your question.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question with the permissions.

Comment: The permissions of `libz.so.1` looks fine. You could try `strace -o /tmp/mysql.strace command－used-to-start-mysql`, and this `/tmp/mysql.strace` may give you the hints why MySQL cannot open that library.

Comment: Are you running  mysql with -privileged option??

Comment: same question here https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4704

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That trace also just signifies that the libz.so.1 gives a permission denied. I have updated the question with the output.

Comment: @Rahul R Dhobi: nope, I'm not in privileged mode and yes, I added that as an issue for the dotCloud, but they closed it even though it is not fixed yet (for me at least).

Comment: @jakobht What is the output of `ls -ld /lib` and `ls -ld /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, your mysql cannot access these two directories.

Comment: @leeduhem, I tried your commands, but both libraries have read and execute permissions for `others` (updated the question with the output).  Can the Docker containerization mess with permissions?

Comment: This might be related to [docker issue #783](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/783). If you can try switching to the devicemapper or btrfs storage backends to try again, that would be awesome. Also, if you can provide a full Dockerfile (that anyone can just build+run to reproduce the issue), that would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @jpetazzo, thanks a lot! Your idea by changing to the devicemapper driver (haven't tried btrfs) solved it. Could you please add an answer.

Comment: GitHub issues: https://github.com/orchardup/docker-mysql/issues/5 https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4704 https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/783 https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-mysql/issues/5

Comment: I have to add this, since I faced the same issue. I fixed it a bit in a different way. So, what I did is: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lib32z1`. I have to mention that I am using crops/poky:ubuntu-16.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I solved the issue by using the devicemapper storage backend, as suggested by @jpetazzo.

Steps I carried out:

1. Stopped the `docker` deamon
2. Started the `docker` deamon with command `docker -d -s="devicemapper"`
3. Ran the `docker run` on the Dockerfile command again. And it worked without any problems.

Comment: The btrfs backend is good for overcoming this issue as well. Just make sure /var/lib/docker is on a btrfs volume, and it automatically gets used.

Answer (score 9):

Deleting the container solve this problem for me.

**Update**: That solution worked not so long.

So I kept searching and found [something related with Apparmor](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4704#issuecomment-64021810).

If you have mysql installed on your host, Apparmor may restrict access of this shared library for mysql installed on your docker container. The following fixed the problem:

```
#Type this on your host terminal
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have mysql-server installed on your host machine, then it installs an apparmor profile for mysqld. For me, the problem went away after I disabled the mysqld apparmor profile on the host with the following commands:

> sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
>   sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

Of course, this also means that apparmor will be disabled for mysqld on your host. I don't use mysqld so I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try 

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server

Comment: As stated on https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4704, he already tried that and it didn't work... Mentioning sources is always a good idea.

Comment: As mentioned I have already tried that, and the Dockerfile also runs the apt-get update. Output of $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list is deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main, if that is what you mean by sources?